# Get html data in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

How can i get data in a table, that is stored as html data, with sql in SQL Server 2010? 
In the table I see the data in the column like this:

`<div style="font-weight: normal; text-decoration: none">my message</div>`

What a need as result after executing the sql query is: `my message`

I use this sql code:

```
USE LcsLog
GO
SELECT * FROM Messages
```

And I get 0 records as result, without an error message.

Comment: If your SELECT query doesn't return any records, what are you doing to be able to "see the data in the column"?

Comment: I see the data in the table, but a need a query to search in the table with a where. Sorry the sql statement was not complete.

Comment: Select * from Messages where body like 'message'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get zero rows, you have no data in the `Messages` table. You won't get an error.

When you *do* put HTML data into that column, SQL Server won't process it or change it.

Check that you are looking at the correct table in the correct schema, for example `SELECT * FROM dbo.Messages`

Edit, now we know the problem...

```
SELECT * FROM Messages WHERE body LIKE '%message%'
```

Comment: @lander - In a `LIKE` query, and `'%'` means "any number of any character".  So, `'%message%'` means "the string 'message' *anywhere* inside the search string".  Where as, `'message%'` would mean "the string 'message' as the *start* of the search string.